# React Modal confirm doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to ReactJS. In my component AllHeroes.js I expect when I click Delete, a Modal shows Yes/No option.

This is the reference: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/

However the Modal doesn't show as a popup, it appears right below the form without any style.

Here is my code of AllHeroes.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link, BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import AddHero from './AddHero';
import EditHero from './EditHero';
import { Button, ButtonToolbar, Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';


class AllHeroes extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      show: false
    }

    this.OnEditHandle = this.OnEditHandle.bind(this);
    this.OnDeleteHandle = this.OnDeleteHandle.bind(this);
    this.handleShow = this.handleShow.bind(this);
    this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
  }


  OnEditHandle(id) {
    //const id = arguments[0];
    window.location = '/Edit/' + id;
  }

  OnDeleteHandle(id) {
    debugger
    this.setState({
      show: true
    })
  }

  handleClose() {
    this.setState({ show: false });
  }

  handleShow() {
    this.setState({ show: true });
  }


  render() {

    let closeModal = () => this.setState({ show: false })

    return (

      <div className="container">
        <h1>All Heroes</h1>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>Id</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Dob</th>
              <th>Stocked</th>
              <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
            {
              this.props.GetAllHeroes().map(item => (
                <tr key={item.Id}>
                  <td>{item.Id}</td>
                  <td>{item.Name}</td>
                  <td>{item.Dob.toLocaleString()}</td>
                  <td>{item.Stocked.toString()}</td>
                  <td>{item.Price}</td>
                  <td><button onClick={() => this.OnEditHandle(item.Id)}>Edit</button></td>
                  <td><button onClick={() => this.OnDeleteHandle(item.Id)}>Delete</button></td>
                </tr>
              ))
            }
          </tbody>
        </table>


        <Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.handleClose} animation={true}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Delete</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>Are you sure to delete this Hero?</Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button variant="secondary" onClick={() => this.handleClose}>
              No
            </Button>
            <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => this.handleClose}>
              Yes
            </Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AllHeroes;
```

Please help to display the Modal properly as this reference.

[image]

Comment: did u import bootstrap css file?

Comment: please send me the reference or npm syntax. Thanks

Comment: this should be in your app import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"

Comment: Please refer this https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-bootstrap for integrating bootstrap into your react app.

Comment: @adel so yes I add import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css' and it works well. Thank you. You didn't post an answer so I cant vote sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to import the Bootstrap stylesheets. You can clearly see it with the "Button" and "Modal" component.

As stated in the `react-bootstrap` documentation :

> Because React-Bootstrap doesn't depend on a very precise version of Bootstrap, we don't ship with any included css. However, some stylesheet is required to use these components.

You should then also install `bootstrap` in your project

```
npm install --save bootstrap
yarn add bootstrap
```

And import the `.css` file in your `src/index.js`

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

Answer (score 2):

here you go add:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. It will be helpful for future users as well.